# Can't View Full Set: Self Join - Compare where Column1 = and Column2 <>

Tags: mysql, resultset, self-join

I have a table `customershipments` with customer records. Columns `Item` and `OrderNumber`. I want to see a full set where `Item` is on more than one, unique `OrderNumber`.

```
SELECT 
    distinct
    cs.item
    ,cs.ordernumber
FROM 
    customershipments cs
JOIN 
    customershipments cs2 
        ON cs.item = cs2.item
        AND cs.ordernumber <> cs2.ordernumber
WHERE
    AND cs.cdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
    AND cs.isactive = 1 
    AND cs.item <>''
    AND cs.hostcompany_id =19
ORDER BY 
    cs.item, cs.ordernumber
```

This does Identify the `items` that I want, but only returns the first `OrderNumber` and not the second. UNLESS there are more than TWO `OrderNumber` for an `item` then it DOES show me ALL cases. I can't figure out why. Like I said this works well enough to point out the records (based on item) that I need to manage, but it doesn't show me an exhaustive list of the ordernumbers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a self-join.  Just use aggregation.  To get the list of items:

```
select item
from customershipments cs
where cs.cdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK and
      cs.isactive = 1 and
      cs.item <> '' and
      cs.hostcompany_id =19
group by item
having count(distinct ordernumber) > 1;
```

You can then join this back to get the list of orders:

```
select cs.*
from (select item
      from customershipments cs
      where cs.cdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK and
            cs.isactive = 1 and
            cs.item <> '' and
            cs.hostcompany_id =19
      group by item
      having count(distinct ordernumber) > 1
     ) i join
     customershipments cs
     on cs.item = i.item;
```

Or, get the list of order numbers on one line:

```
select item, group_concat(ordernumber)
from customershipments cs
where cs.cdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK and
      cs.isactive = 1 and
      cs.item <> '' and
      cs.hostcompany_id =19
group by item
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: But I need where where an item has more than one ordernumber and the ordernumbers are Different.

Comment: @user3242558 . . . Then use `count(distinct)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: Oh - geez. Yes. You are right. And the reason I didn't get the list I thought I should have was because there were `items` in the result set only listed once and the other combinations that didn't show were because they didn't meet the cdate interval condition. Chalk that up to friday evening burnout. Thanks! I can't upvote, but this helped.